# how to return the search results in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to write a script which can return me the result whenever the regex meet.I have some difficulties in writing the regex i guess.

Content of My input file is as below:

```
 Number a123;
     Number b456789 vit;
 alphabet fty;
```

I wish that it will return me the result of a123 and b456789, which is the string after "Number  " and before ("\s" or ";"). 
I have tried with below cmd line:

```
 my @result=grep /Number/,@input_file;
 print "@results\n";
```

The result i obtained is shown below:

```
  Number a123;
     Number b456789 vit;
```

Wheareas the expected result should be like below:

```
a123
b456789
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perls `grep` function selects/filters all elements from a list that match a certain condition. In your case, you selected all elements that match the regex `/Number/` from the `@input_file` array.

To select the non-whitespace string after `Number` use this Regex:

```
my $regex = qr{
  Number     # Match the literal string 'Number'
  \s+        # match any number of whitespace characters
  ([^\s;]+)  # Capture the following non-spaces-or-semicolons into $1
             # using a negated character class
}x;          # use /x modifier to allow whitespaces in pattern
             # for better formatting
```

My suggestion would be to loop directly over the input file handle:

```
while(defined(my $line = <$input>)) {
  $line =~ /$regex/;
  print "Found: $1" if length $1; # skip if nothing was found
}
```

If you have to use an array, a `foreach`-loop would be preferable:

```
foreach my $line (@input_lines) {
  $line =~ /$regex/;
  print "Found: $1" if length $1; # skip if nothing was found
}
```

If you don't want to print your matches directly but to store them in an array, `push` the values into the array inside your loop (both work) or use the `map` function. The map function replaces each input element by the value of the specified operation:

```
my @result = map {/$regex/; length $1 ? $1 : ()} @input_file;
```

or

```
my @result = map {/$regex/; length $1 ? $1 : ()} <$input>;
```

Inside the `map` block, we match the regex against the current array element. If we have a match, we return `$1`, else we return an *empty list*. This gets flattened into invisibility so we don't create an entry in `@result`. This is different form returning `undef`, what would create an undef element in your array.

Comment: Thanks Amon.Would like to confirm with u if the reges should be lk the one shown below as i get nothing for my @result?

my $regex=qr{Number\s+([^\s;]*?)}x;

Comment: @Steven yeah, the regex mykhal gives is probably optimal. If you need the strictness, the sarathi regex will work as well, although it might be too confining. I updated the answer, and it works for me.

Comment: Yup. i tried to use the regex given by mykhal.it works...Thanks..=)

Answer (score 2):

if your script is intended as a simple filter, you can use

```
$ cat FILE | perl -nle 'print $1 if /Number\s+([^\s;]+)/'
```

or

```
$ cat FILE | perl -nle 'for (/Number\s+([^\s;]+)/g) { print }'
```

if there can be multiple occurences on the same line.

Comment: Thanks mykhal.cat can get what i expected exactly.However, cat is only work in unix.i cant used cat in my perl script.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'if(/Number/){s/.*\s([a-zA-Z])([\d]+).*$/\1\2/g;print}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
Number a123;
 Number b456789 vit;
 alphabet fty;


> perl -lne 'if(/Number/){s/.*\s([a-zA-Z])([\d]+).*$/\1\2/g;print}' temp
a123
b456789
>
```